# Como restringir datas no MySQL e no SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se consigo restringir determinadas datas no próprio banco de dados, e não no código.

Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela que registra data de entrada e data de saída. Seguem alguns requisitos.

- A data de entrada nunca poderá ser maior que a data de saída
- A data de entrada não pode ser menor que um determinado ano (2000 por exemplo)
- Não posso ter uma data de saída sem ter uma data de entrada

O que eu quero saber, é se essas restrições podem ser **feitas no próprio banco de dados** e não na aplicação.

O meu banco de dados é o MySQL, mas seria legal saber a possibilidade disso para o SQL Server também.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SQL Server - *Check constraints*

O SQL Server oferece o recurso de *check constraints*. Para adicionar uma *check constraint*, você faz o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE sua_tabela ADD CONSTRAINT CK_nome_da_sua_constraint
CHECK (data_entrada <= data_saida)
```

## MySQL

No MySQL, o ideal seria usar *check constraints*. Entretanto, o MySQL não implementa *check constraints* completamente (ele implementa apenas *constraints* de chave primária, chave estrangeira, `NOT NULL` e `UNIQUE`). O MySQL até entende a sintaxe delas, mas não as implementa de fato, tal como descrito no [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Assim sendo, há três possibilidades:

### 1. *Triggers*:

A ideia é colocar duas *triggers* para validar os dados, uma para a inserção (`BEFORE INSERT`) e a outra para alteração (`BEFORE UPDATE`):

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER validar_datas_insert BEFORE INSERT ON sua_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT (new.data_entrada <= new.data_saida)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Datas inválidas';
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER validar_datas_update BEFORE UPDATE ON sua_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT (new.data_entrada <= new.data_saida)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Datas inválidas';
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

### 2. Inserir em uma *view* com validação

Uma outra ideia é usar uma *view*. Neste caso você deve fazer inserções e alterações (`INSERT`s e `UPDATE`s) apenas por meio da *view*. Fazer isso direto na tabela base vai contornar as verificações. Eis o código:

```
CREATE VIEW sua_view AS
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE data_entrada <= data_saida
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

### 3. Coluna virtual

A ideia é adicionar uma coluna fictícia `NOT NULL` que é preenchida de forma válida apenas quando as datas estão no intervalo correto e com `NULL` em caso contrário, o que vai resultar em um erro devido ao `NOT NULL` e impedir a inserção ou alteração. Eis um exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE sua_tabela ADD COLUMN
validar_data CHAR(0) AS
(CASE WHEN data_entrada <= data_saida THEN '' END)
VIRTUAL NOT NULL;
```

É interessante de se notar que essa coluna não consome espaço físico no banco de dados por ser do tipo `CHAR(0) VIRTUAL NOT NULL`.

## Observações

Para manter o conceito simples, eu só coloquei o teste da data de entrada ser antes da data de saída (`data_entrada <= data_saida`). Para fazer o teste completo, acho que você precisaria de várias condições:

- `data_entrada IS NULL OR data_saida IS NULL OR data_entrada <= data_saida`
- `data_entrada IS NULL OR year(data_entrada) >= 2000`
- `data_saida IS NULL OR year(data_saida) >= 2000`
- `NOT (data_entrada IS NULL AND data_saida IS NOT NULL)`

É possível combinar todas elas (ou seletivamente algumas delas) em uma única expressão ao envolvê-las com parênteses e combinar com `AND`s, mas acho que fica mais fácil mantê-las separadas. Cada uma dessas condições viraria um `IF NOT (...)` dentro das *triggers* ou uma coluna virtual separada. No caso da *view*, você seria obrigado a combiná-las em uma só expressão na cláusula `WHERE`.

## MariaDB

O [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) é um *fork* do MySQL, criado após a aquisição da Sun (junto com o MySQL) pela Oracle. Foi desenvolvido pelo mesmo criador original do MySQL, que decidiu criar o *fork* por rejeitar a Oracle tomando conta do projeto.

[O MariaDB implementa as *check constraints* que o MySQL deixou a desejar a partir da versão 10.2.1](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7563). A sintaxe deve ser a mesma que a do SQL Server.

## Referências bibliográficas:

- http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/
- https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7563

Comment: muito boa resposta Victor. Me interessei mais pelas triggers, você acha que é a melhor opção das 3?

Comment: @DiChrist Isso vai por opinião pessoal, mas acho que a abordagem 3 (coluna virtual) é a melhor.

Comment: Beleza, assim que eu puder testar e resolver meu problema, dou sua resposta como aceita :)

Comment: @DiChrist Pensando bem, há uma abordagem melhor do que a 1, 2 ou 3. Editei a resposta para demonstrá-la - Simplesmente use o MariaDB. :D